# Vercel deployment errors out when installing bcrypt

Tags: deployment, vercel

Whenever vercel trys to build my webpage it has an error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/bcrypt
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-05-27T05_36_03_200Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

Can't seem to find an answer on this one. I did change the build to npm start like it is in my package.json I use npm node src/app.js. If I don't use that then it will build it but my request just error out.

Edit: So I was able to switch to bcryptjs and that fixed that issue I'm still getting errors for the GLIBC from node now.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike most packages you install from npm/yarn, `bcrypt` often has errors when deploying to cloud environments because it's precompiled.

You require either `GLIBC_2.27` or `GLIBC_2.28` in your deployment environment... I haven't done this before with Vercel, but I'll give you a solution I've tried on other platforms.

**Use Prebuilt Binaries**. For NodeJS modules that have native code (like `bcrypt`) there are prebuilt binaries available. These binaries are compiled with older versions of `GLIBC`. Since they're backward compatible, they should work in most production environments. To use them, you might need to adjust your npm install command to something like this:

```
npm install bcrypt --build-from-source
```

Alternatively (easier but hackier), you can remove `node_modules/bcrypt` from your `.gitignore` file to push them to the server using whichever build you have locally. This is fine for independent projects. However, a more permanent solution is preferred when working on an actual application for an organization or with a small team.

Comment: So I was able to switch to bcryptjs and that fixed that issue I'm still getting errors for the GLIBC from node now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I was getting this same error because I was declaring node itself as a dependency in my `package.json` file. This is not needed.

In `package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "node": "^20.7.0",
  }
```

You want to **remove** the "node" line. After doing that, I was able to deploy to Vercel without getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

using nextjs coding all in typeScript, I uninstalled node and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation of Vercel's infrastructure, [which currently only supports GLIBC_2.26](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2105#discussioncomment-5641005).

The recommended workarounds are to either downgrade the dependency to one that uses an older version of GLIBC (likely what changing to bcryptjs did for you), or to use CI/CD (e.g. Github Actions) to handle deployments to Vercel via the CLI.