# Deploy next.js project using Vercal failure

Tags: next.js, vercel

Im working on the [tutorial project](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/setting-up-your-database) of Next.js and having a problem while trying to deploy using Vercal account.

The following error occur in the build stage

Console output:

```
[18:27:10.151] Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1 (Hive)
[18:27:10.391] Cloning github.com/eden-hason/nextjs-dashboard (Branch: main, Commit: 
e9417ad)
[18:27:10.708] Cloning completed: 317.565ms
[18:27:10.762] Previous build cache not available
[18:27:10.964] Running "vercel build"
[18:27:11.454] Vercel CLI 32.5.6
[18:27:12.229] Warning: Detected "engines": { "node": ">=18.17.0" } in your 
`package.json` that will automatically upgrade when a new major Node.js Version is 
released. Learn More: http://vercel.link/node-version
[18:27:12.244] Installing dependencies...
[18:27:31.071] npm ERR! code 1
[18:27:31.072] npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/bcrypt
[18:27:31.074] npm ERR! command failed
[18:27:31.074] npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
[18:27:31.074] npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found 
(required by node)
[18:27:31.074] npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found 
(required by node)
[18:27:31.075] 
[18:27:31.076] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: 
/vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-11-26T16_27_13_420Z-debug-0.log
[18:27:31.100] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
[18:27:31.382]
```

`packge.json` content:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "next build",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "prettier": "prettier --write --ignore-unknown .",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check --ignore-unknown .",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.18",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@types/node": "20.5.7",
    "@vercel/postgres": "^0.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.15",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "next": "^14.0.2",
    "node": "^18.17.0",
    "postcss": "8.4.31",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3",
    "typescript": "5.2.2",
    "zod": "^3.22.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "@types/react": "18.2.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.14",
    "@vercel/style-guide": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "9.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "0.5.4"
    },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.17.0"
  }
}
```

After some [google searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76345524/vercel-deployment-errors-out-when-installing-bcrypt) I found that it might be related to the `bcrypt` package but none of the solutions I tried worked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like changing the node version solve this issue
[image: configuration page screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As mentiond this [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/2867) the problem is that you include `node` itself in your `dependencies`.

```
npm uninstall node
```

After updating the `package.json` try to redeploy your application.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me
[image: vercel project settings]

Comment: Please also describe the solution. [Images aren't very accessible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577).